# How to configure an AngularJS App using configuration blocks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m currently trying to configure an AngularJS app. After some searching I found [this idea](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) at the official *angularjs.com* page. This seems like a pretty good way to configure an application before it´s runtime. In my case I want to read in a few parameters and path-values from a simple `.xml, .properties` or something comparable using some javascript in the configure block. But I have no clue neither how to implement my idea using this concept nor if this actually is a good way to solve the problem with configuring an app using an external file.

For better demonstration I build an simple app as a working base. In the end I want to configure the values of `CONFIG.PATH.BASE` and `CONFIG.PATH.REST` with an external file.
I´m pretty sure you guys out there are able to help me.

So here is the pretty simple code:

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('ConfigTestApp', []);

var CONFIG = CONFIG || {};

CONFIG.PATH = {
 BASE: "localhost:8080",
 REST: "/sample/api/rest"
}

app.controller('ShowConfigController', ['$scope', function($scope){

 var vm = this;
 
 vm.greeting = "Basic Configuration";
 vm.basePath = CONFIG.PATH.BASE;
 vm.restPath = CONFIG.PATH.REST;

 var d = new Date();
 vm.timestamp = d.getTime();

}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title>HtmlFrontendBase</title>
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body data-ng-app="ConfigTestApp" class="indexpage">


<div ng-controller="ShowConfigController as ShowConfCtrl">
 <h1>{{ShowConfCtrl.greeting}}</h1>

 BasePath: {{ShowConfCtrl.basePath}}<br/>
 RestPath: {{ShowConfCtrl.restPath}}<br/>
 Timestamp: {{ShowConfCtrl.timestamp}}<br/>
</div>


<!-- configurations and constants -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

**EDIT:**
The application will be running on a tomcat server with a single initial configuration.

Comment: Do you want the configuration file to reside on the server, or on the client? If you're looking for a client-side solution, take a look at cookies. If you're doing it server-side, you'll need to load the file with your server backend and export the configuration values to your front-end templates.

Comment: @IvoCoumans Edited the post with some additional information. The file should stay on the server